# Use JAX-RS without being implementation specific

Tags: java, jax-rs

I have a service that I want to consume in a few projects in basically the same way. I'd like to simplify the process of sending and receiving data to and from these projects, so I would like to make a client jar that handles the process of packing and unpacking jaxrs responses/requests and include that in my other projects.

However, to use any jax-rs objects, I have to be dependent on a specific implementation of jax-rs. In my little client library I have to include jersey (or resteasy or cxf) to have access to any of the jax-rs imports. If I were to include this jar in any of my other projects, they'd be forced to use that rest implementation as well.

Is there a way to create a single project jar that utilizes jax-rs objects, that would use the jax-rs implementation of the consuming container instead of having many nearly identical client projects that just include a different jax-rs implementation?

Essentially, I want my project wars to include a jar that will handle packing and unpacking jax-rs rest objects that use whatever implementation of jax-rs the war project uses.

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.0

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Nice, is that basically just the set of jax-rs interfaces that the implementations would consume? If I imported that in the client, would it know to use the consuming wars imported implementation of jax-rs?

Comment: Yeah, it would know to use the implementation's Client

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Classes from the `javax.ws.rs.*` package are portable and are expected to work across different JAX-RS implementations. Use the following dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Classes from the following packages are implementation specific and you don't want to use them directly when you want your code to be portable across different implementations:

- Jersey: `org.glassfish.jersey.*`
- RESTEasy: `org.jboss.resteasy.*`
- Apache CXF: `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.*`

However such classes *must be in the classpath during runtime*.

---

The JAX-RS Client API was introduced in JAX-RS 2.0 and enhanced in JAX-RS 2.1 with reactive capabilities. Check the API [documentation](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/client/package-summary.html) for details.

Prior JAX-RS 2.0, any client support was vendor specific and not portable. The proxy-based clients provided by most of the vendors are not portable either.

The JAX-RS Client API can be used as follows:

```java
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
Response response = client.target("http://example.org/hello").request("text/plain").get();
```

In the above code, a [`javax.ws.rs.client.Client`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html) instance will be created using the default [`javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.html) implementation class provided by the JAX-RS implementation provider.

---

If you are interested, check the documentation for the [`Client`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html) implementations:

- Jersey: [`org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClient`](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/client/JerseyClient.html)
- RESTEasy: [`org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClient`](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.5.1.Final/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/client/jaxrs/ResteasyClient.html)
- Apache CXF: [`org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.spec.ClientImpl`](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/client/spec/ClientImpl.html)